# How to dynamically change order of links

Tags: javascript

I have something like this:

```
<div class="list-group list">
    <a href="blabla" id="1" data-order="1">Hello</a>
    <a href="blabld" id="2" data-order="2">World</a>
</div>
```

No I try to change the order of the links dynamically with plain Javascript.

Does anyone have any suggestion, how to do so?

My Goal is this:

```
<div class="list-group list">
    <a href="blabld" id="2" data-order="1">World</a>
    <a href="blabla" id="1" data-order="2">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can change child elements order in JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850389/how-i-can-change-child-elements-order-in-js)

Comment: Oh, wait, plain JS and not jQuery... Sorry, not a duplicate. How do I unflag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function sort(r) {
    var $list = document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0];
    var listGroupA = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var $listGroupA = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < listGroupA.length; ++i) {
        $listGroupA.push(listGroupA[i]);
    }
    $listGroupA.sort(function (a, b) {

        return r * (a.getAttribute('data-order') - b.getAttribute('data-order'));

    });
    for (var i = 0; i < $listGroupA.length; i++) {
        $list.removeChild($listGroupA[i]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < $listGroupA.length; i++) {
        $list.appendChild($listGroupA[i]);
    }
}
var reverse = 1;
$('#sort').click(function () {

    reverse = reverse * -1;
    sort(reverse);
});
```

And [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arjzbmw5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the last list item and create one more item and append it to the container div like this :

```
var world = document.getElementById("2");
var id = world.id;
var data = world.getAttribute("data-order");
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0];

div.removeChild(world);
var newA = document.createElement("a");
div.appendChild(newA);
newA.id = id;
newA.dataset.order = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jLpoLacq/1/)

```
Reorder = function()
{    
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  document.getElementsByClassName('list').innerHTML = "";
  var content  =  "";
      for(i = x.length; i > 0; i--)
      {
          content = content + x[i - 1].outerHTML;
      }
  document.getElementsByClassName('list').innerHTML = content;
}
```

The above code will take the existing items into an array and clear the contents. Now, they will be added to the div. I've used the classname here to add it to the div.