# Javascript code to shift the last image to the first between multiple images

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="cat.jpg" id="cat" onclick="alertfunction()">
        <img src="dog.jpg" id="dog" onclick="alertfunction()">
        <img src="frog.jpg" id="frog" onclick="movefunction()">
        <img>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function alertfunction() {
            alert("Don't click me, click the frog");
}
    function movefunction(){
        
    }


</script>
</html>
```

Here, what i need help with, Whenever the user clicks the last picture, move to first.
Please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850389/how-i-can-change-child-elements-order-in-js/25850715

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can do this with flex and order in the CSS, check the code below, instead of images, i used divs with colors.

```css
.maindiv {
display: flex;
}

#frog {
padding: 10px;
width: 20px;
background: red;
}

#cat {
padding: 10px;
width: 20px;
background: blue;
}

#dog {
padding: 20px;
width: 10px;
background: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="maindiv">
        <div id="cat" onclick="alertfunction()">cat</div>
        <div id="dog" onclick="alertfunction()">dog</div>
        <div id="frog" onclick="movefunction()">frog</div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function alertfunction() {
            alert("Don't click me, click the frog");
}
    function movefunction(){
    if (document.getElementById('frog').style.order == '1') {
        document.getElementById('frog').style.order = '3';
        document.getElementById('cat').style.order = '1';
        document.getElementById('dog').style.order = '2';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('frog').style.order = '1';
        document.getElementById('cat').style.order = '2';
        document.getElementById('dog').style.order = '3';
    }
        
    }


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks ... but when the user clicks on frog it should go to the original form

Comment: What do you mean by the original form?

Comment: It's not a good practice to change element positions with flex order styles. It should only be used for styling purposes and what OP asks for is a functionality.

Comment: When the user clicks on the frog again it should go back go to last image.

Comment: @Aminator Edited the snippet, when the frog is clicked again, then it should go back to the last.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the source of the image whenever the user clicks on an image for instance:

```
let cat = document.getElementById("cat");
let frog = document.getElementById("frog");
function moveFunction() {
  if(frog.src == "frog.jpg"){
    frog.src = "cat.jpg";
  }
  else {
    frog.src = "frog.jpg";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to search for is DOM manipulation in Javascript. Here is a simple way to do what you ask for. I tried to make it as explanatory as possible.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="animals">
        <img src="cat.jpg" id="cat">
        <img src="dog.jpg" id="dog">
        <img src="frog.jpg" id="frog">
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    // animals variable here is a NodeList which is kind of like Array,
    // but it is not enumerable (you cannot loop over it).
    var animals = document.querySelectorAll('#animals > *');

    // Here we convert it to an actual Array.
    var animalsArray = Array.from(animals);

    // We are going to add click listeners on every single of them.
    animalsArray.forEach(function (animal) {

        // Add an event listener to this img element.
        animal.addEventListener(

            // The listener should observe click events.
            'click',

            // The listener will call this function
            // when a click event is triggered.
            function (event) {

                // This is the order number of the clicked animal image.
                // Assuming that you have 3 images on the page, this number
                // will be 0, 1 or 2.
                // 0 marking the image as the first of rest, and 2 marking it
                // as the last of them.
                var positionOfThisAnimal = animalsArray.indexOf(this);

                // animalsArray.length will give you the number of images in
                // the `animalsArray` Array.
                // If the position of the clicked animal image is smaller than
                // the highest it can be (which is `2` for 3 images), it is not
                // the last one, and we will alert the user with a message.
                if (positionOfThisAnimal < animalsArray.length - 1) {
                    alert("Don't click me! Click the frog.");

                    // Because all we have to do for these not-the-last-one
                    // images is to alert the user, we are returning a void
                    // (empty) result here which effectively stops the function
                    // from executing the rest of the lines we have below.
                    return;
                }

                // Here we are taking the clicked animal image (which is the
                // last one in the list) and we are moving it to the first
                // place in the div with ID "animals".
                document.querySelector('#animals').prepend(this);
            },

            // This `false` means the listener should not be marked as passive.
            //
            // Passive listeners are asynchronous, meaning that the browser
            // will *not* wait for your function to complete executing before
            // continuing to wait for other user inputs like mouse moves or
            // keyboard strokes.
            // 
            // The browser will wait for active listeners. This has a downside
            // though. If your function takes too long to complete, the user
            // will notice that their browser (or just the current tab) freezes
            // and won't let user interact with the page until the execution
            // is completed.
            false,
        );
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const img1 = document.querySelector('#cat');
                const img2 = document.querySelector('#dog');
                const img3 = document.querySelector('#frog');
                const imgUrl = img3.src;
                img1.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    if(img1.src === imgUrl) {
                        let temp = img1.src;
                        img1.src = img2.src;
                        img2.src = img3.src;
                        img3.src = temp;
                        let temp2 = img1.id;
                        img1.id = img2.id;
                        img2.id = img3.id;
                        img3.id = temp2;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Don\'t click me, click the frog');
                    };
                });
                img2.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    alert('Don\'t click me, click the frog');
                });
                img3.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    
                    if(img3.src === imgUrl) {
                        let temp = img1.src;
                        img1.src = img3.src;
                        img3.src = img2.src;
                        img2.src = temp;
                        let temp2 = img1.id;
                        img1.id = img3.id;
                        img3.id = img2.id;
                        img2.id = temp2;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Don\'t click me, click the frog');
                    };
                    
                });
```

```css
img {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
            }
```

```html
<div>
            <img src="cat.jpg" id="cat">
            <img src="dog.jpg" id="dog">
            <img src="frog.jpg" id="frog">
        </div>
```